# Composer not installing wordpress plugins through dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, composer-php, dockerfile

I am using docker-compose to build a wordpress environment. My plan is to use composer to install plugins and themes I need. When I run docker-compose build everything builds fine and no issues. When I run docker-compose up I see all my containers running, composer included. When I navigate to the wordpress build only the default themes and plugins are installed. My question is why aren't my plugins and themes being installed. What am I missing?

I tried to include files I thought were relevant

**fileStructure**

```
/
 config/
   /composer/
      Dockerfile
      composer.json
   /wordpress/Dockerfile
   /database/Dockerfile
   /phpmyadmin/Dockerfile

 dist/
   /wp-content/
      /themes/
      /plugins/
      /uploads/

docker-composer.yml
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "repositories":[
    {
        "type":"composer",
        "url":"https://wpackagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "wpackagist-plugin/akismet":"dev-trunk",
    "wpackagist-plugin/wordpress-seo":">=7.0.2",
    "wpackagist-theme/hueman":"*"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile Composer**

```
FROM composer/composer:php7

# Install composer
WORKDIR /var/www/html/wp-content

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

COPY composer.json /var/www/html/wp-content
# COPY composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
# COPY ./ /var/www/
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

**Dockerfile Wodrpess**

```
# start with the latest wordpress and php image
FROM wordpress:5.1.1-php7.3-apache

# Set our environment variables for logging into wordpress
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_HOST database:3306
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_USER username
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD password

# Expose a port to run on
EXPOSE 80
```

**Dockerfile Database**

```
# start with the mysql image
FROM mysql:5.7

# Set our environment varibales for logging into the DB
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD UKoBMndyEY
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE wordpress
ENV MYSQL_USER username
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD password

# Copy the database table dependencies into our image DB
COPY  ./includes /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

# Expose a port to run on
EXPOSE 3306:3306
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./dist/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/database
    volumes:
      - datab:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  composer:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/composer
    restart: 'no'
    image: "composer"
    volumes:
      - ./dist/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
  phpmyadmin:
    build:
        context: ./config/docker/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
volumes:
    datab: {}
```

Comment: The composer service doesn't really need to run since it does all the work during build time. And at build time time volume mapping you are doing in docker-compose is not available. I suggest to use a multi-stage build for your wordpress service: first stage should be the compose part (your compose dockerfile) and the second stage should copy the contents of /var/www/html/wp-content to the wordpress image and continue with whatever work you are doing in the wordpress Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @Mihai thanks for your reply. Do you have an example of what this might look like? I removed the composer service from the docker-compose file. First I ran the composer docker file to install composer but I am confused on the second part as to what I am copying. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, can you post the wordpress Dockerfile that you are using?

Comment: I have updated my question with both wordpress and database dockerfiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my comment you need to rearrange a bit your project.

The composer folder and service can disappear. Move the contents of the folder composer in the folder wordpress.

Then the Dockerfile in the wordpress folder should look like this:

```
FROM composer/composer:php7 as build

# Install composer
WORKDIR /var/www/html/wp-content

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

COPY composer.json /var/www/html/wp-content
# COPY composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
# COPY ./ /var/www/
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize

FROM wordpress:5.1.1-php7.3-apache

# Set our environment variables for logging into wordpress
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_HOST database:3306
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_USER username
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD password

COPY --from=build /var/www/html/wp-content /var/www/html/wp-content

# Expose a port to run on
EXPOSE 80
```

The docker-compose.yml can be now simplified like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/wordpress
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/database
    volumes:
      - datab:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  phpmyadmin:
    build:
        context: ./config/docker/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
volumes:
    datab: {}
```

I hope this works for you. Otherwise let me know the error and I will look at it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. This worked for me!